# Hibernate, jpa is it possible to map a hashmap<object,object>?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three classes, one of them is an immutable key.

```
@Entity
public class Key {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private int x;
    private int z;

    @OneToMany(??)
    private Person person;

    @OneToMany(??,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Building building;


    @Transient
    private int hashcode;
    .... getters, setters, overrided hascode and equals methods
}
```

Second one is just a standart class annotated with jpa annotations. There is also bidirectional mapping between all classes.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long key;

     @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "person")
     private Set<Key> keys;

     @OneToMany(??,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Building building;
     ....     getters, setteres
}
```

Third class is also a jpa entity which holds references to all keys and persons in a hashmap. Is is possible to map my classes with jpa and hibernate if i would like to keep bidirectional mapping? Is my structure even considered as a good pratice or should i remove bidirectional mapping, however i would prefer to keep it

@Entity 
public class Building {

```
  @JoinTable (??)/something else
  Map<Key, Person> map;
```

}

Comment: A field of type Person or Building is clearly NEVER a OneToMany ... it is OneToOne or ManyToOne. A Set field is not a ManyToOne either ... it is OneToMany or ManyToMany. All of this is to be found in ANY JPA documentation

Comment: An entity that holds all keys and persons in a HashMap doesn't make sense. That's what database tables are for. If you want to get the person associated to a given key, you don't need any map: you just get the Key from the database and call key.getPerson().

Comment: @JBNizet i got your point but Im doing this as a cache due to performace reasons. I want to load the whole table by calling session.get(Building.class,id) and all its relations into memory. The schema i posted here is simplyfied, the project is not a webserverice. During the programm runtime i cant wait until key.getperson executes query. Once i load root object (building) i want to have all key and persons in memory.

Comment: The cache doesn't need to be an entity. Just execute a JPQL query that loads all the keys and their persons, and keep their state in your cache. An entity, basically, represents a row of a table. That's it.

Comment: That said, you're probably pre-optimizing: the mapping of your entities isn't even correctly done yet, and you already assume you'll have performance problems. If the whole thing fits in memory, the database will have it in memory, and loading it from the database should be very fast, most probably fast enough. And if it wasn't you could use a second-level cache rather than a hand-made cache.